# Can dd be used for regular small files?

Tags: linux, dd

Man `dd`:

> dd - convert and copy a file

I'm leaning to use `dd`. Strangely after copying 1 byte text file becomes much smaller:

```
$ block_size=1; device_to_edit=/media/ramdrive/a; device_from=/media/ramdrive/b; echo "aaaaaaaaaa">$device_to_edit; echo "bbbbbbbbbb">$device_from; cat $device_to_edit; cat $device_from; dd if=$device_from of=$device_to_edit count=1 seek=2 skip=2 bs=$block_size; cat $device_to_edit
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0,000156688 s, 6,4 kB/s
aab
```

It said `1 byte copied`, why end of file is gone?

Added:

As comment suggested, `conv=notrunc` fixes it. But from `man`:

> conv=CONVS
> convert the file as per the comma separated symbol list

I did not want to convert a file. When reading about copying block devices, I have not seen this operand. Is it always needed when not all file (e.g. one 512 bytes block in /dev/sdb: USB disk) is changed?

Comment: `block_size=1; dd count=1 bs=$block_size;` You're asking it to copy just one byte. If you want to copy some bytes to the middle of the file without affecting the rest, add `conv=notrunc`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, thank you. Could you please have a look at "added"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is this:

```
block_size=1; 
dd ... count=1 seek=2 skip=2 bs=$block_size;
```

you're asking `dd` to copy just one byte. But, by default, it truncates the output file, so that the end of file is where `dd` finished.

```
$ echo abcdefgh > test1
$ echo 12345678 > test2
$ dd count=1 bs=1 skip=2 seek=2 if=test1 of=test2
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.000179375 s, 5.6 kB/s
$ cat test2; echo
12c
```

The GNU manpage I have doesn't seem to explicitly say that, but [the POSIX description does](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/dd.html):

> `of=file`
> Specify the output pathname; [...] If `seek=expr` is specified, but `conv=notrunc` is not, the effect of the copy shall be to preserve the blocks in the output file over which dd seeks, but no other portion of the output file shall be preserved. (**If the size of the seek plus the size of the input file is less than the previous size of the output file, the output file shall be shortened by the copy.** [...])

To prevent that, add the `conv=notrunc` option:

> `notrunc`
> do not truncate the output file

```
$ echo 12345678 > test2
$ dd conv=notrunc count=1 bs=1 skip=2 seek=2 if=test1 of=test2
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.00019385 s, 5.2 kB/s
$ cat test2
12c45678
```

`notrunc` doesn't make it modify the data that actually is copied, so it's not a "conversion" in that sense, even though it's taken as a flag to `conv`.

Note that if `count=` is given, `dd` does exactly that many `read()` calls, which means that if you read from a device that can give short reads, the amount of data actually read is not `count` times `bs`.

Comment: You can also replace `of=file conv=notrunc` with `1<> file` in Bourne-like shells.

Answer (score 1):

Should have looked at full documentation, `man dd`:

```
Full documentation at: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/dd>
       or available locally via: info '(coreutils) dd invocation'
```

> ‘of=FILE’
> Write to FILE instead of standard output.  Unless ‘conv=notrunc’ is
> given, ‘dd’ truncates FILE to zero bytes (or the size specified
> with ‘seek=’).